# Calculating number of hours in Excel with Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, openpyxl

I have a Dataframe with a column listing the duration of some events in minutes.
I would like to calculate in a new column what the duration is in hours. The format of the data would be a date - time one.
The durations can be up to 3000+ minutes, resulting in a number of hours that would be well above 24:00:00.
Currently my formula is this one:

```
df['Durée contractuelle (h)'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Durée contractuelle (mn)']/(60*24) ,axis=1)
```

However, I'm getting float results in my new column like 1.638, 1.892, etc.
How do I  transform it, in order to obtain the right format? The expected result for;

```
2,355 minutes is 39:15:00 (hours), and not 1,638.
```

Comment: If you want hours and not days, why do you divide the number of minutes by `(60*24) `?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Good question. The formula was written as such (not by me) in the Excel file, and the result was indeed 39:15 so I didn't notice the 24. If I remove it, then my result is 39,25 (hours) but I would still need to format it in the HH:MM format which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: ```import datetime
sec = 2355
ty_res = datetime.timedelta(minutes = sec)
print(ty_res)``` have this solution with output ```1 day, 15:15:00```

Comment: Excel consideres datetimes to be numbers. Use a Python datetime type so that the correct number format will be applied.

Answer (score -1):

try this

````py
def myfunc(x):
        # test value -> x = 2355
        h = x/60
        m = int(60*(int(str(h).split(".")[1])/100))
        h = int(str(h).split(".")[0])
        s = int(60*(int(str(m/60).split(".")[0])/100))
        m = int(m)
        h = int(h)
        s = int(s)
        print(f'{h}:{m}:{s}')
        return f'{h}:{m}:{s}'

df['Durée contractuelle (h)'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x) ,axis=1)

```
````

Comment: thanks a lot, it works almost perfectly. Is there a way to cap the number of characters for h, m and s to 2? Otherwise, I'm getting results like 39:19000000000000:189999999999.

Comment: Do you know the number that caused the error or is there something I can reproduce?

Comment: @Hetal I changed the answer, test again

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
Probably a parenthesis issue, it seems there's one too many in "str(int(str(h).split(".")[1])/100))" so I removed the last one, then I have the TypeError.

Comment: @Hetal try again

Comment: Use the string formatting options of datetimes in Python.